# How to downgrade Xamarin.ios in mac machine?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

when i updated the visual studio version 8.4.1 in my mac it automatically updated the xamarin.ios to latest version then some of the functionality like search bar not working in build.I need to downgrade the Xmarin.ios Please help me how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio for Windows
Downgrading Xamarin.iOS to the version 10.12 in Visual Studio means that you need to downgrade VS to the version 15.3.
You need to contact the support team for the download link since they provide only the link for the version N-1.

I'll just leave the links, they may be useful to someone.
For Xamarin Studio:
It's possible, either downloading Xamarin.iOS from here:

https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.12.0.18.pkg

or directly from the repository, which contains every version:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases